# How to create a hash with each item from 3 or more arrays

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and would like to create hashs from each items of array. Say h1 with all 1st items of array. h2 with all 2nd items and so on.
Ex: Lets say I have 4 arrays

```
a1 = ['fname1', 'fname2', 'fname3', 'fname4']
a2 = ['lname1', 'lname2', 'lname3']
a3 = ['add1', 'add2', 'add3', 'add4']
a4 = ['pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3', 'pin4']
```

I would like to create 4 hashes

```
h1 = {:fname => "fname1", :lname => "lname1", :address => 'add1', :pin => 'pin1'}
h2 = {:fname => "fname2", :lname => "lname2", :address => 'add2', :pin => 'pin2'}
h3 = {:fname => "fname3", :lname => "lname3", :address => 'add3', :pin => 'pin3'}
```

and either:

```
h4 = {:fname => "fname4", :lname => "", :address => 'add4', :pin => 'pin4'}
```

or:

```
h4 = {:fname => "fname4", :address => 'add4', :pin => 'pin4'}
```

Please note if the value does not exists in array, it has to be handled differently, e.g. set to `''` or be skipped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. Is it possible to not include the element in hash rather than setting it to null or blank(''). Say h4 = {:fname => "fname4", :address => 'add4', :pin => 'pin4'}, without(lname), since it is not available in a2

Comment: Sure, you can [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#compact-method) each hash within the `map` block to remove `nil` values. I've updated my answer. (you should update your question, too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#zip-method) to combine the arrays element-wise and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#map-method) to turn them into hashes:

```
hashes = a1.zip(a2, a3, a4).map do |fname, lname, address, pin|
  { fname: fname, lname: lname, address: address, pin: pin }
end
#=> [
#     {:fname=>"fname1", :lname=>"lname1", :address=>"add1", :pin=>"pin1"},
#     {:fname=>"fname2", :lname=>"lname2", :address=>"add2", :pin=>"pin2"},
#     {:fname=>"fname3", :lname=>"lname3", :address=>"add3", :pin=>"pin3"},
#     {:fname=>"fname4", :lname=>nil, :address=>"add4", :pin=>"pin4"}
#   ]
```

To handle `nil` values, you could use `||` to provide a default value:

```
{ fname: fname || '', lname: lname || '', ... }
```

or call [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#compact-method) to omit these values:

```
{ fname: fname, lname: lname, ... }.compact
```

If you prefer to have separate variables, you can use:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 = hashes
```

or without the intermediate variable:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 = a1.zip(a2, a3, a4).map do ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
new_array = a1.zip(a2, a3, a4).collect{ |e| [[:fname, :lname, :add, :pin], e].transpose.to_h }

=> [{:fname=>"fname1", :lname=>"lname1", :add=>"add1", :pin=>"pin1"}, {:fname=>"fname2", :lname=>"lname2", :add=>"add2", :pin=>"pin2"}, {:fname=>"fname3", :lname=>"lname3", :add=>"add3", :pin=>"pin3pin4"}, {:fname=>"fname4", :lname=>nil, :add=>"add4", :pin=>nil}]

new_array[0]
=> {:fname=>"fname1", :lname=>"lname1", :add=>"add1", :pin=>"pin1"}

new_array[1]
=> {:fname=>"fname2", :lname=>"lname2", :add=>"add2", :pin=>"pin2"}

new_array[2]
=> {:fname=>"fname3", :lname=>"lname3", :add=>"add3", :pin=>"pin3pin4"}

new_array[3]
=> {:fname=>"fname4", :lname=>nil, :add=>"add4", :pin=>nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

For data consistency, I suggest you change your source data to avoid problem with missing values.

This is my guess, but if not possible, **just ignore this answer**.

Change this way, adding blank string where element is missing, **I also blanked other values**:

```
a1 = ['fname1', 'fname2', '', 'fname4']
a2 = ['lname1', 'lname2', 'lname3', '']
a3 = ['add1', 'add2', 'add3', 'add4']
a4 = ['pin1', '', 'pin3', 'pin4']
```

Once data is consistent, you can do something like:

```
keys = [:fname, :lname, :address, :pin]
data = [a1, a2, a3, a4]

data.transpose.map { |datum| keys.zip(datum).to_h }
#=> [{:fname=>"fname1", :lname=>"lname1", :address=>"add1", :pin=>"pin1"}, {:fname=>"fname2", :lname=>"lname2", :address=>"add2", :pin=>""}, {:fname=>"", :lname=>"lname3", :address=>"add3", :pin=>"pin3"}, {:fname=>"fname4", :lname=>"", :address=>"add4", :pin=>"pin4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is really about converting two arrays, `keys` and `values`, where `keys.size >= values.size`, to a hash. It is merely applied to several instances of the array `values`.

When `keys.size > values.size`, `values` must, in effect, be padded with `keys.size - values.size` empty strings (or `nil`s):

```
def convert_to_hash(keys, values)
 keys.zip(values).map { |k,v| [k, v || ''] }.to_h
end
```

See [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip), particularly, *"If the size of any argument is less than the size of the initial array, nil values are supplied"*.

For example,

```
keys = [:fname, :lname, :address, :pin]
```

```
a1 = ['fname1', 'fname2', 'fname3', 'fname4']
a2 = ['lname1', 'lname2', 'lname3']
a3 = ['add1', 'add2', 'add3', 'add4']
a4 = ['pin1', 'pin2', 'pin3', 'pin4']
```

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 = [a1, a2, a3, a4].map { |values| convert_to_hash(keys, values) }
  #=> [{:fname=>"fname1", :lname=>"fname2", :address=>"fname3", :pin=>"fname4"},
  #    {:fname=>"lname1", :lname=>"lname2", :address=>"lname3", :pin=>""},
  #    {:fname=>"add1", :lname=>"add2", :address=>"add3", :pin=>"add4"},
  #    {:fname=>"pin1", :lname=>"pin2", :address=>"pin3", :pin=>"pin4"}]
```

Write `h[keys[i]] = values[i]` if missing values are to be converted to `nil`s.

The operative line of the method could be replaced with

```
keys.each_index.with_object({}) { |i,h| h[keys[i]] = values[i] || '' }
```

or

```
keys.zip(values + ['']*(keys.size - values.size)).to_h
```

Note that the latter, unlike the other two, works if `values` contains one or more `nil`s.

An important reason for writing this as a separate method is that it facilitates testing.